# PHP: "move_uploaded_file()" failing without any helpful info

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an uploaded file, and when trying to save it to the filesystem, it is simply failing.
My `var_export($_FILES['bom_file'])` produces

```
array (
  'name' => '_bomUpload.tester.csv',
  'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'tmp_name' => 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php837A.tmp',
  'error' => 0,
  'size' => 265,
)
```

And here's my `move_uploaded_file()` attempt: (I've tried with several diff file paths)

```
$file_path = 'C:/wamp/NetBeansProjects/BomProject/application/uploads/boms/testfile.csv';  // For Testing ---->
$testVar = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bom_file']['name'], $file_path);
echo ($testVar)? 'The file has been uploaded': 'There was an error uploading the file';
echo '<pre>UPLOAD?: ', var_export($testVar), '</pre>';  // For Testing ---->
```

I am consistently getting just the error message and `$testVar` is FALSE.

What am I missing??

Comment: Make sure the user that the web server is running under has write access to the destination location. Make sure the folder is not "Read-Only" in Properties.

Comment: @Dutchie432: "Is your web server windows? Unix?" `'tmp_name' => 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php837A.tmp',` o_O

Comment: Didn't see that there. [shrug].

Comment: Try `$testVar = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bom_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path);` - the file should still be in tmp_name as that point

Comment: Yeah .. I prob _should_ have explicitly mentioned that I'm on a WAMP server, but you figured it out ;) .. @erni perfect! That did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$testVar = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bom_file']['name'], $file_path);
```

to

```
$testVar = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bom_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path);
```

The `name` is only the "name" of the file. The actual uploaded file reference is in the `tmp_name` array key

Comment: This worked perfectly ... and @ernie posted this too at almost the same exact time ... works great ... thanks!

Comment: Well ... _Almost!!_ According to that little code block, everything is going through just fine, but I'm getting a Fatal Error. I've got a big 'ol stack trace to sort through, but the meat and potatoes is "_Uncaught exception 'Exception', Could not open C:\wamp\tmp\php9F9C.tmp for reading, File does not exist._" ... wtf ?? :)

Comment: After plenty of head scratching, I just used `rename($_FILES['foo']['tmp_name'], $newPathAndName)` instead ... just in case it helps someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$testVar = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bom_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path);` - the file should still be in tmp_name as that point